# error for secr.fit when trying to fit a hybrid mixture model 'Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : '

Tags: r, spatial, mixture-model

I cannot resolve the below error after having already considered the vignettes and a search on forums.

I am undertaking a multi session analysis using the package secr in R (developed by Murray Efford).

When I run this model

```
 fit_age0 <- secr.fit(bothCH, mask = mask,  detectfn = 2, trace = F, hcov = 'age')
```

I get this error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) :    mixture models fail when the first
>   detector is not used on the first day.

The code used to create the relevant capthist file is below. I would reduce this down further if I knew where the specific problem was. Please let me know if there is additional information that is needed to help answer this question.

```
library(secr)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(GISTools)
library(raster)
library(readxl)
#--------------------

###Input files and create capthist####
captfile <- "captfile_both.xlsx"
trapfile <- "trapfile_both.csv"

suggest.buffer(bothCH)
#########
#276 395#
#########

# quick and biased estimate of sigma (metres)
initialsigma_both <- RPSV(bothCH, CC = TRUE) 
initialsigma_both 
##############
#$`OUT`      #
#[1] 85.34081#
#            #
#$IN         #
#[1] 118.8134#
##############

buffer <- 800
bothCH <- read.capthist(captfile = captfile, trapfile = trapfile,
                        skip = 1, detector = "proximity",
                        covnames = c("age"))            

bothCH <- split(bothCH, grepl('IN',rownames(traps(bothCH))), bytrap = TRUE)

# drop last 2 occasions for OUT (no cameras working)
bothCH[[1]] <- subset(bothCH[[1]], occasions=1:78)
usage(traps(bothCH[[1]])) <- usage(traps(bothCH[[1]]))[,1:78]

#### Clear repeat observations
bothCH <- reduce(bothCH, dropunused = FALSE)    
verify(bothCH)

session(bothCH) <- c('OUT',"IN")
```

Examples of my trap file and capt file layouts are below.

[traps file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jaktc.png)

[Capt file format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiCyT.png)

Thanks in advance for any advice as I am really struggling to complete this analysis.

[Full capt file (dummy data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29t4c.png)

[Full trap file (actual data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eozZt.png)

Comment: please provide the reproducible data.

Comment: Unfortunately Cyrus I'm obligated by a research contract not to share data publically which is why I only provided an example of the data. I'm hopeful that somebody with knowledge of spatially explicit capture recapture and the package secr will have encountered this error or know what sorts of issues may usually lead to such an error.

Comment: You can always provide sample data by simulation/random generation...

Comment: Great idea Cyrus. I should have thought of that but it has been a very tough week. I have attached two new tables with the data by editing the original post. It had occurred to me to change the data point for OUT01 from a 0 to  1 and see if that helps solve the problem. The problem with that occurred when trying to read in the edited file. For the following function I get this error when using the edited file.

Comment: captfile <- "captfile_both.csv"
trapfile <- "trapfile_both.csv"

bothCH <- read.capthist(captfile = captfile, trapfile = trapfile,
                        skip = 1, detector = "proximity",
                        covnames = c("age"))

Comment: Error in read.table(file, row.names = 1, as.is = T, colClasses = colcl,  : 
  duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed